# Why won't my car start but is cranking? No ignition puls,e no injector pulse, but the fuel pump is working

Tags: toyota, corolla, cranks-wont-run

My car is toyota corolla 1995 and it has 5a fe engine. Recently I went about 50km and stopped the car. Now I can't start it. Engine is cranking but not starting.

- Fuel pump is working
- No ignition pulse
- No injector pulse

Can self diagnose by connecting two pins of ODB port by reading check engine bulb blinking codes but there aren't any error code.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 4):

Two things come to mind.
1: crankshaft position sensor. Many times when this fails it will not throw a code. With a fresh battery, turn the engine over and watch the tach. If it doesn't jump a little, you may not be getting a signal from the crank sensor. They are cheap and usually easy to get to. So I would try replacing that and see what happens.
2: the other thing that comes to mind is the security system may be failing. Look in your owners manual and see what your security dash lights are supposed to be doing. If the security system appears to be functioning, just replace crank sensor.

Comment: Can you say where is crank sensor located in 5A-FE engine??

Comment: @THUSHANTHAPRITHIRAJ A google for "5a-fe engine crankshaft position sensor location" will lead to you to photos of the location, and videos on how to replace it.

Comment: Typically it is found in the engine block near the harmonic balancer (crankshaft pulley)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is an electrical fault in the car. Since cranking works, the battery is most likely fine. Please check the fuses.  Check for wiring damages (cuts or burns) under the hood.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).